# Problem with JavaScript closure and possible call/apply solution

Tags: javascript

I have a hierarchical relationship between the following the objects:

- spaceObject (base class of sorts)
- star (inherits from spaceObject)
- planet (inherits from spaceObject)

star just passes thru the params passed in to spaceObject but planet tried to update two of the parameters.

When star calls sun.draw() that works as expected

But, when planet calls mercury.draw(), the that.x and that.y are undefined.

I feel like I'm not getting how to use call/apply and maybe there is a solution in there that would let my x and y be available to the draw() method.

(also, not sure why snippet below does not work here in SO but it does show just the sun on my local)

Note: I can make this work with "class" but I'm looking for a solution without using the class keyword.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  function drawName(xOverride, yOverride) {
    context.font = "14px monospace";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(name, x, y - radius - 5);
  }

  function draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }

  return {
    name,
    color,
    radius,
    x,
    y,
    draw,
  };
};

const star = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  return that;
};

const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  
  that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
  that.y = params.parent.y;
  
  // when "mercury.draw()" is called below, I want this draw method to include that.x and that.y
  // at the moment, x and y are null and the below apply does not work
  //that.draw = params.draw.apply(that);
  
  return that;
};

const sun = star({
  name: "Sun",
  color: "yellow",
  radius: 40,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
});

const mercury = planet({
  name: "Mercury",
  color: "green", // "#ffffff",
  radius: 1.85,
  dist: 59,
  parent: sun,
});

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function mainUpdate() {
  clear();
  sun.draw();
  mercury.draw();
}

mainUpdate();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <title>Simple Solar System</title>
    
    <style>
    body,
canvas {
    background-color: #000000;
}
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <canvas id='solar-canvas' width='1500px' height='650px'></canvas>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The answer marked below is correct.  He just did not include the final code so I'm adding the working code with that added `this` for history.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  function drawName(xOverride, yOverride) {
    context.font = "14px monospace";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(name, x, y - radius - 5);
  }
  
  function draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
  
  return {
    name,
    color,
    radius,
    x,
    y,
    draw,
  };
};

const star = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  return that;
};

const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
  that.y = params.parent.y;
  return that;
};

const sun = star({
  name: "Sun",
  color: "yellow",
  radius: 40,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
});

const mercury = planet({
  name: "Mercury",
  color: "green", // "#ffffff",
  radius: 1.85,
  dist: 59,
  parent: sun,
});

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function mainUpdate() {
  clear();
  sun.draw();
  mercury.draw();
}

mainUpdate();
```

Comment: The problem here is you're using a pseudo class system with pseudo inheritance. Why not write actual classes and use actual inheritance?

Comment: @ChrisG JavaScript does not have "actual" classes. Classes in JavaScript are just syntactical sugar meant to mask the prototypes that really make it work. Inheritance in JavaScript is prototypical.

Comment: Is there a way I can get my planet.draw method pickup the new x and y?

Comment: Here's how to do this using "syntactic sugar": https://jsfiddle.net/649jvups/

Comment: @ScottMarcus noted

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG  I should have mentioned that I know how to make this work with the class keyword. I'm trying to do it without class. I'm also not looking for an discussion of whether I should use class or not.

Comment: No problem, here's the version without `class`: https://jsfiddle.net/2gkahyvn/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG.  I hate to make you keep working, but I'm trying not to use prototype. I get that class uses prototype. I'm wondering if I'm on a fool errand trying to do this with call or apply?

Comment: JavaScript has exactly one way that it implements inheritance: prototypes. `call` and `apply` are not inheritance, they are just ways to invoke code and supply context for the `this` keyword.

Comment: @Pete *"The answer marked below is correct. He just did not include the final code"* The final code has been included in my answer all along. It's just in collapsible code snippets to not make the answer too long. Try clicking the "Show code snippet"s in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're main issue is one of scoping. I'll add some comments to clarify what is happening.

First let's have a look at:

```js
const that = spaceObject(params);

that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
that.y = params.parent.y;
```

If we now take a look at the `spaceObject` function, let's see what actually changes.

```js
// The spaceObject params don't change, because you assign properties.
const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {

  // ...

  // The object returned is the object that is mutated by the assignment
  // statements.
  //
  //     that.x = ...
  //     that.y = ...
  // 
  return { // <- this object is mutated
    name,
    color,
    radius,
    x,
    y,
    draw,
  };
};
```

So whenever you refer to `x` and `y` (or any other parameters for that matter) you are not using the current values of the object. You're using the initial values passed to the `spaceObject` function.

Instead use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) within a `function` to refer to the object upon which you evoke the method. In the statement `mercury.draw()`, `this` in `draw()` will be set to `mercury`.

```js
function draw() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  function drawName(xOverride, yOverride) {
    context.font = "14px monospace";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(this.name, this.x, this.y - this.radius - 5);
  }

  function draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }

  return {
    name,
    color,
    radius,
    x,
    y,
    draw,
  };
};

const star = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  return that;
};

const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  
  that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
  that.y = params.parent.y;
  
  return that;
};

const sun = star({
  name: "Sun",
  color: "yellow",
  radius: 40,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
});

const mercury = planet({
  name: "Mercury",
  color: "green", // "#ffffff",
  radius: 1.85,
  dist: 59,
  parent: sun,
});

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function mainUpdate() {
  clear();
  sun.draw();
  mercury.draw();
}

mainUpdate();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <title>Simple Solar System</title>
    
    <style>
    body,
canvas {
    background-color: #000000;
}
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <canvas id='solar-canvas' width='1500px' height='650px'></canvas>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Alternatively you can also reference the returned object directly instead of using `this`. You do need to assign it to a variable, otherwise there would be no label to reference the returned object.

```js
const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  const item = { name, color, radius, x, y };

  // ...

  return item;
};
```

Then assign the methods the the created `item`.

```js
item.draw = function () {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = item.color;
  context.arc(item.x, item.y, item.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
};
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  const item = { name, color, radius, x, y };

  item.drawName = function (xOverride, yOverride) {
    context.font = "14px monospace";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(item.name, item.x, item.y - item.radius - 5);
  };

  item.draw = function () {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = item.color;
    context.arc(item.x, item.y, item.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  };

  return item;
};

const star = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  return that;
};

const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  
  that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
  that.y = params.parent.y;
  
  return that;
};

const sun = star({
  name: "Sun",
  color: "yellow",
  radius: 40,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
});

const mercury = planet({
  name: "Mercury",
  color: "green", // "#ffffff",
  radius: 1.85,
  dist: 59,
  parent: sun,
});

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function mainUpdate() {
  clear();
  sun.draw();
  mercury.draw();
}

mainUpdate();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <title>Simple Solar System</title>
    
    <style>
    body,
canvas {
    background-color: #000000;
}
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <canvas id='solar-canvas' width='1500px' height='650px'></canvas>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

This might leave you wondering. Is there any difference between the two solutions?

The answer to that is **yes**.

`this` is set if you invoke a method. `item` (or whatever you've called it) always reference the object created in `spaceObject`.

They behave the same when invoked like:

```
mercury.draw()
```

However if you take that method and invoke it as a function results will be different.

```
const draw = mercury.draw;
draw()
```

When `draw` is defined using `item` (or whatever you named it), it will still refer to `mercury`. Thus `mercury` is successfully drawn.

However, since there is no object upon which you invoke the method, `this` will be set to `window` (global object) or `undefined` if the function is defined within [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Resulting in an unsuccessfully draw.

The same applies if you "move" the method to another object.

```
const someOtherObject = { x: 1, y: 2, radius: 3, color: "red" };
someOtherObject.draw = mercury.draw;
someOtherObject.draw();
```

In the above `someOtherObject.draw()` will assign `this` to `someOtherObject`. So when defined with `this`, `someOtherObject` will be drawn.

Yet if you had it defined with `item` it would still refer to the properties of `mercury`. So the above would draw `mercury`.

---

If you want to use neither of these techniques there is a third option that allows you to use just `x`, `y`, etc, without `this` or `item`. To get this to work there is 1 rule you have to follow: **Don't mutate the object after it's been created.**

```js
const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  
  // NOT allowed, mutating object after creation
  that.x = params.parent.x + params.dist;
  that.y = params.parent.y;
  
  return that;
};
```

Instead you could transform the parameters beforehand and pass the correct values to start with.

```js
const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject({
    ...params,
    x: params.parent.x + params.dist,
    y: params.parent.y,
  });
  
  return that;
};
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

const spaceObject = function ({ name, color, radius, x, y }) {
  function drawName(xOverride, yOverride) {
    context.font = "14px monospace";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(name, x, y - radius - 5);
  }

  function draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }

  return {
    name,
    color,
    radius,
    x,
    y,
    draw,
  };
};

const star = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject(params);
  return that;
};

const planet = function (params) {
  const that = spaceObject({
    ...params,
    x: params.parent.x + params.dist,
    y: params.parent.y,
  });
  
  return that;
};

const sun = star({
  name: "Sun",
  color: "yellow",
  radius: 40,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
});

const mercury = planet({
  name: "Mercury",
  color: "green", // "#ffffff",
  radius: 1.85,
  dist: 59,
  parent: sun,
});

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function mainUpdate() {
  clear();
  sun.draw();
  mercury.draw();
}

mainUpdate();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <title>Simple Solar System</title>
    
    <style>
    body,
canvas {
    background-color: #000000;
}
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <canvas id='solar-canvas' width='1500px' height='650px'></canvas>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I hear you thinking, how do I change properties if I can't mutate my object? The answer, create a new object with updated properties.

Say you wanted to increment the `x` of `mercury` by `1`. You would then do:

```js
const newMercury = spaceObject({ ...mercury, x: mercury.x + 1 });
// or if you don't care about the old mercury variable
mercury = spaceObject({ ...mercury, x: mercury.x + 1 });
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using "this" but I'm thinking you have convinced me that it is unavoidable.

Comment: @Pete I've added a third option that works with just `x` and `y` without adding `this` or `item`.